# How to prevent 404 page flicker on redirect outside the website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

I do redirects with `createRedirect` action inside `createPages` hook.
The function that uses redirect looks like this:

```
const redirects = [
    {
        fromPath: '/start',
        toPath: 'https://www.youtube.com/',
        redirectInBrowser: true,
        force: true,
        statusCode: 200,
        isPermanent: true
    },
    {
        fromPath: '/start/',
        toPath: 'https://www.youtube.com/',
        redirectInBrowser: true,
        force: true,
        statusCode: 200,
        isPermanent: true
    },
    {
        fromPath: '/blogs',
        toPath: '/blog/',
        redirectInBrowser: true,
        force: true,
        statusCode: 200,
        isPermanent: true
    },
    {
        fromPath: '/blogs/',
        toPath: '/blog/',
        redirectInBrowser: true,
        force: true,
        statusCode: 200,
        isPermanent: true
    },
]

const createRedirects = ({createRedirect}) => {
    redirects.map(e => createRedirect(e))
}

module.exports = {
    createRedirects
};
```

gatsby-node.js is only this:

```
const {createRedirects} = require("./utils/redirects");
const {createBlogPages} = require('./utils/blog');
const {createDocsPages} = require('./utils/docs');
const {createCategoryPages} = require('./utils/category');

exports.createPages = async ({actions, graphql, reporter}) => {
    createRedirects(actions);
    await createBlogPages(actions, graphql, reporter);
    await createDocsPages(actions, graphql, reporter);
    await createCategoryPages(actions, graphql, reporter);
}
```

The 404 page includes the "window" hack which has to prevent this page from appearing all over the website, according to this issue:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../components/header/header';
import Footer from '../components/footer/footer';
import BottomContent from '../components/bottomContent/bottomContent';
import Helmet from "react-helmet";


const NotFound = () => {
    const browser = typeof window !== "undefined" && window;

    return (browser && <>
        <Header route={''}/>
        <Helmet>
            <title>UP9 | 404</title>
        </Helmet>
        <div className="content" style={{margin: '5rem 0 8rem', 'text-align': 'center'}}>
            <h1 style={{'font-size': '5rem', 'line-height': '1', 'margin-bottom': '1.5rem'}}>404</h1>
            <h3 className={'text-light'}>Oops, seems like this link is not supported</h3>
        </div>
        <BottomContent />
        <Footer />
    </>)
}

export default NotFound;
```

Comment: Are you hosted on Netlify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All client-side redirects are susceptible to have a blink, since the JavaScript code that triggers the redirect will be managed by the browser itself.

Ideally, all the redirections should be treated on the server-side. If you are using Netlify as a provider, you can create redirects using the [`_redirects`](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/) file or some [other plugins](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-client-side-redirect/).

Comment: Yes, It came to me, that there won't be a better solution, but unfortunately, it is hosted on GCP, where _redirects or .htaccess doesn't work...

Comment: Then I'm afraid you won't find an ideal solution :/

Comment: True, at the moment I've added the meta-tag redirects, for faster reaction and later will try the rewrite rules, which may work, but I'm not sure 100%. 
Thanks for help anyway :)